# optimization in R -solnp

Tags: r

I've get the two functions from OLS for mean and std dev from a set of coded data. I'm using the solnp to perform the optimization by minimize the function std dev subject to target mean function=500 with below R-code.

However, my coded data for x is set only from -1 to 1 but data can go out of the interval. How to show the optimized value for mean and std dev?

```
fn1=function(x)    {S=intercept1+x1S*x[1]+x2S*x[2]+x3S*x[3]+x4S*x[1]*x[2]+x5S*x[1]*x[3]+x6S*x[2]*x[    3]+x7S*x[1]^2+x8S*x[2]^2+x9S*x[3]^2
}     eqn1=function(x)    {m=intercept2+x1m*x[1]+x2m*x[2]+x3m*x[3]+x4m*x[1]*x[2]+x5m*x[1]*x[3]+x6m*x[2]*x[    3]+x7m*x[1]^2+x8m*x[2]^2+x9m*x[3]^2
}
constraint=c(500)
x0 = c(-1, -1, -1)
LG=solnp(x0, fun = fn1, eqfun = eqn1,eqB = constraint)
```

results in

```
Iter: 1 fn: 69.1474  Pars:   2.59803 11.49848 -1.42309
Iter: 2 fn: 16.6575  Pars:   0.11328  2.47160 -1.13136
Iter: 3 fn: -25.4959     Pars:  -1.29057 -4.34931  0.11716
Iter: 4 fn: 18.7180  Pars:  -0.80939 -0.48576 -0.60873
Iter: 5 fn: -30508.7839  Pars:  -38.31650  71.04339 -18.61200
Iter: 6 fn: 8659561.9838     Pars:  -1212.62541  -171.17422   -91.98102
Iter: 7 fn: -92947015.8433   Pars:   1553.64673 -4069.16237   993.85107
Iter: 8 fn: 145185.9376  Pars:   2732.20221 -1444.17722   579.73287
Iter: 9 fn: -53715280.8638   Pars:   19547.74783 -10608.46092   4207.13900
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to perform the optimization with the following code. First, I found a reasonable estimate with DEoptim using a minimum square approach. Afterwards, I used the solnp function.

```
library(DEoptim)
library(Rsolnp)

intercept1 <- 4
x1S <- 10
x2S <- 25
x3S <- 35
x4S <- 0.05
x5S <- 1
x6S <- 2
x7S <- 5
x8S <- 10
x9S <- 15

intercept2 <- 2
x1m <- 3
x2m <- 6
x3m <- 7
x4m <- 0.5
x5m <- 0.5
x6m <- 3
x7m <- 5
x8m <- 11
x9m <- 12

fn_Loss <- function(x, constraint, bool_Print = FALSE)
{
  S <- (intercept1 + x1S * x[1] + x2S * x[2] + x3S * x[3] + x4S * x[1] * x[2] + x5S *x[1] * x[3] +
        x6S * x[2] * x[3] + x7S * x[1] ^ 2 + x8S * x[2] ^ 2 + x9S * x[3] ^ 2)
  
  m <- (intercept2 + x1m * x[1] + x2m * x[2] + x3m * x[3]+ x4m * x[1] * x[2] + x5m * x[1] * x[3]+ x6m * x[2] * x[3]+
          x7m * x[1] ^ 2 + x8m * x[2] ^ 2 + x9m *x[3] ^ 2)
  
  if(bool_Print == TRUE)
  {
    print(S)
    print(m)
  }
  
  loss_Val <- S ^ 2 + 100000000 * (m - constraint) ^ 2
  return(loss_Val)
}     


obj_DEoptim <- DEoptim(fn = fn_Loss, lower = c(-1000, -1000, -1000), upper = c(1000, 1000, 1000),
                       control = list(itermax = 100000), constraint = 500)

fn_Loss(x = obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem, constraint = 500, bool_Print = TRUE)



fn1 <- function(x)
{
  S <- (intercept1 + x1S * x[1] + x2S * x[2] + x3S * x[3] + x4S * x[1] * x[2] + x5S *x[1] * x[3] +
          x6S * x[2] * x[3] + x7S * x[1] ^ 2 + x8S * x[2] ^ 2 + x9S * x[3] ^ 2)
  
  return(S)
}     

eqn1 <- function(x)
{
  m <- (intercept2 + x1m * x[1] + x2m * x[2] + x3m * x[3]+ x4m * x[1] * x[2] + x5m * x[1] * x[3]+ x6m * x[2] * x[3]+
          x7m * x[1] ^ 2 + x8m * x[2] ^ 2 + x9m *x[3] ^ 2)
  
  return(m)
}

constraint <- c(500)
x0 <- obj_DEoptim$optim$bestmem
LG <- solnp(x0, fun = fn1, eqfun = eqn1, eqB = 500)

fn_Loss(x = LG$pars, constraint = 500, bool_Print = TRUE)

par1 
263.7334 
par1 
500 
par1 
69555.29
```

Here the standard deviation is 263.7334. The mean is 500 and the loss function for the minimum-square is 69555.29.